# Basics in Logging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

Do Log files ever get too large?

I log a lot of variables in a twitter script, that is running indefinitely. Does this pose a risk for my server or are there maintenance issues I should consider?

What are the best practices for managing log files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could issue cron jobs or if you are running on a windows machine: use the task scheduler.

[Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at something like [logrotate](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) to keep the log files to a reasonable size and number.